# SQL query : how to check existence of multiple rows with one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table `MyTable`:

```
PROG    VALUE
-------------
1       aaaaa
1       bbbbb
2       ccccc
4       ddddd
4       eeeee
```

now I'm checking the existence of a tuple with a certain id with a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS IT_EXISTS
FROM MyTable
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND PROG = {aProg}
```

For example I obtain with aProg = 1 :

```
IT_EXISTS
---------
   1
```

I get with aProg = 3 :

```
IT_EXISTS
---------
   0
```

The problem is that I must do multiple queries, one for every value of PROG to check.

What I want is something that with a query like

```
SELECT PROG, ??? AS IT_EXISTS
FROM MyTable
WHERE PROG IN {1, 2,3, 4, 5} AND {some other condition}
```

I can get something like

```
PROG     IT_EXISTS
------------------
   1        1
   2        1
   3        0
   4        1
   5        0
```

The database is Oracle...

Hope I'm clear

regards

Paolo

Comment: How can you tell that `PROG` 3 and 5 are _supposed to_ exist? Do you have a table of all possible `PROG` values - or - is it all sequential integers?

Comment: the prog values are from others tables. The table of the question has only a subset of the all prog values

Comment: If the prog values to be checked are not hard coded as your question suggests, then you really want to edit your question to clarify that further.

Comment: I recommend you either follow @Asaph 's answer or make use of a `LEFT JOIN` of this table to the table that stores all your `PROG` values.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear, the progs are from other tables but not used directly: i must specify them in a where clause.

Comment: I'll go with the Asaph first answer, writing some application logic. Thanks to all!

Comment: Its a pity you didn't ask the more general case, where you have more than 2 columns and want to check for multiple entities based on multiple where conditions...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a step back and ask yourself this: Do you really need to return the rows that don't exist to solve your problem? I suspect the answer is no. Your application logic can determine that records were not returned which will allow you to simplify your query.

```
SELECT PROG
FROM MyTable
WHERE PROG IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you get a row back for a given `PROG` value, it exists. If not, it doesn't exist.

### Update:

In your comment in the question above, you stated:

> the prog values are from others tables. The table of the question has only a subset of the all prog values

This suggests to me that a simple left outer join could do the trick. Assuming your other table with the `PROG` values you're interested in is called `MyOtherTable`, something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.PROG,
CASE WHEN b.PROG IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IT_EXISTS
FROM MyOtherTable AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS b ON b.PROG = a.PROG
```

A `WHERE` clause could be tacked on to the end if you need to do some further filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this.  If at most one row can match a prog in your table:

```
select p.prog,
       (case when t.prog is null then 0 else 1 end) as it_exists
from (select 1 as prog from dual union all
      select 2 as prog from dual union all
      select 3 as prog from dual union all
      select 4 as prog from dual union all
      select 5 as prog from dual
     ) p left join
     mytable t
     on p.prog = t.prog and <some conditions>;
```

If more than one row could match, you'll want to use aggregation to avoid duplicates:

```
select p.prog,
       max(case when t.prog is null then 0 else 1 end) as it_exists
from (select 1 as prog from dual union all
      select 2 as prog from dual union all
      select 3 as prog from dual union all
      select 4 as prog from dual union all
      select 5 as prog from dual
     ) p left join
     mytable t
     on p.prog = t.prog and <some conditions>
group by p.prog
order by p.prog;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use (arguably abuse) a [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) to create an arbitrarily long list of numbers (in my example, I've set the largest number to max(PROG), but you could hardcode this if you knew the top range you were looking for). Then select from that list and use EXISTS to check if it exists in MYTABLE.

```
select
      PROG
    , case when exists (select 1 from MYTABLE where PROG = A.PROG) then 1 else 0 end IT_EXISTS
from (
    select level PROG
    from dual
    connect by level <= (select max(PROG) from MYTABLE) --Or hardcode, if you have a max range in mind
) A
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still not very clear where you get the `prog` values to check.  But if you can read them from a table, and assuming that the table doesn't contain duplicate `prog` values, this is the query I would use:

```
select a.prog, case when b.prog is null then 0 else 1 end as it_exists
  from prog_values_to_check a
  left join prog_values_to_check b
    on a.prog = b.prog
   and exists (select null
                 from MyTable t
                where t.prog = b.prog)
```

If you do need to hard code the values, you can do it rather simply by taking advantage of the `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL` function, which allows you to convert a comma-delimited list of values into rows.

```
with prog_values_to_check(prog) as (
  select to_number(column_value) as prog
    from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) -- type your values here
)
select a.prog, case when b.prog is null then 0 else 1 end as it_exists
  from prog_values_to_check a
  left join prog_values_to_check b
    on a.prog = b.prog
   and exists (select null
                 from MyTable t
                where t.prog = b.prog)
```

Note: The above queries take into account that the `MyTable` table may have multiple rows with the same `prog` value, but that you only want one row in the result.  I make this assumption based the `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` condition in your question.